# How to read same input file in reduce task which I read in map task (Mapreduce)

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have been trying to read the file in the reducer which is also the input of the mapper. So is there any way I can get access to that file in reducer?

Comment: Try overriding the setup method? To get the context/filesystem access?

Answer (score 0):

MAPPER & REDUCER also have `protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {}`   just to extends and override  this method  it could help you  to read your file at first .

BTW  you could also  set a global variable to read in mapper  and use in reducer  .
it's better to add the file to  Distributed Cache  with  `job.addCacheArchive()` method

Answer (score 0):

Driver Class

```
    public class MapReduceDriver extends Configured implements Tool
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
        {
            int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new MapReduceDriver(), args);        
            System.exit(exitCode);
        }

        @Override
        public int run(String[] args) throws Exception 
        {
            Configuration conf = getConf();     
            conf.set("myPath", "/home/hdfs_path");
            ....... 
        }
    }
```

Mapper Class

```
    public class MapReduceMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>
    {
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
        {           
            Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
            String myPathStr = conf.get("myPath");
            Path myPath = new Path(myPathStr);
            //code to read from the Path
        }
    }
```

Reducer

```
    public class MapReduceReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text,Text> 
    {
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
        {
            Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
            String myPathStr = conf.get("myPath");
            Path myPath = new Path(myPathStr);
            //code to read from the path
        }
    }
```